Entropy transport and production due to heat
In the book Modern Engineering Thermodynamics- Robert T. Balmer (7.10 Differential Entropy Balance) it is given that

$$dS_Q=\frac{\overline dQ}{T}\tag{7.42}$$
However, the equation cannot be as easily integrated for common nonisothermal heat transfer processes. This problem can be solved by changing the form by introducing the following mathematical identity $$dS_Q = d\left(\frac{Q}{T}\right)+\frac{Q}{T^2}dT\tag{7.44}$$
For a closed system, we may decompose the transport and production terms as follows
$$dS_Q = (dS_T)_Q + (dS_P)_Q$$ comparing the two equations allows us to identify the following terms $$(dS_T)_Q = d\left(\frac{Q}{T}\right)\tag{7.50}$$ $$(dS_P)_Q = \frac{Q}{T^2}dT\tag{7.52}$$

My question is how did he directly compare the terms?

Where in the book does this come from?

Chapter 7, equation 7.44

What page is it on?

page 227 onwards (2011 edition).

You messed up the quote. “Commonnon isothermal” should be “common nonisothermal”

Corrected, thanks.

You’ve left out the equation at the bottom of page 727 which may answer your question

I meant  bottom of pg 227

@BobD That makes sense. Thanks.

I have added the related equation numbers from Berman to your post. I found that the equations you presented are not taken exactly from Berman and that certain text related to your question about the last two equations has been omitted. As this makes it difficult to answer your question.

In a continuum mechanics development, if we divide the differential heat balance by T, we obtain terms like $$\frac{k}{T}\frac{\partial^2T}{dx^2}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left(\frac{k}{T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{k}{T^2}\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)^2$$
The first term on the right is the rate of entropy transport by conduction, and the second term is the positive definite local rate of entropy generation.  See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al, problem 11.D.1.

If there’s a connection between your equation from Bird and the OP’s equation from Balmer, other than the $1/T^2$ term, I can’t see it.

Also, have you ever seen differential entropy production written the way shown in Balman’s last equation ?

@BobD No.  it doesn’t seem correct.

That’s what I thought but can’t prove it.

The "dogma" of heat conduction is that "heat is conserved in conduction". This statement cannot be proved, it is instead the constitutive definition of heat conduction. It is a confusing definition because the terminology "heat" is confusing as this word can be and is used in several non-equivalent ways.
It is much clearer if you only talk about entropy generation and entropy transfer. If  you have two bodies that can interact only through thermal conduction, and their temperature differences is $T_2-T_1=dT$ then if $\Delta S$ entropy leaves the higher temperature, $T_2,$ body entering the conducting medium and then the lower temperature, $T_1,$ body, then the latter will absorb $\Delta S$ and also the entropy generated in the conducting medium between the two bodies. Since we exclude any other interaction but thermal conduction the thermal work $\Delta S dT$ is completely lost, dissipated, when $\Delta S$ entropy drops through $dT$ temperature difference and instead generates $\sigma=\Delta S\frac{dT}{T_1}>0$ entropy. Why is this?
Energetically the higher temperature body loses $\Delta S\; T_2$ thermal energy, "heat", as it enters the connecting conducting medium. Assuming that no other interaction takes place this amount of thermal energy in steady state will pass through the conductor and exactly the same amount will leave at the lower temperature to be absorbed by the other body at $T_1$. But then the  amount of entropy absorbed at $T_1=T_2-dT$ must be $\frac{\Delta S \; T_2}{T_1}=\Delta S + \Delta S \frac {dT}{T_1}.$
In this transport the term $\Delta S=\frac{\Delta S\; T_2}{T_2}$ with $Q=\Delta S \;T_2$ can be viewed as the isothermal part while the term $\Delta S \frac {dT}{T_1}$ as the "production" part.
